# Is it possible to call didChangeDependencies on function 'onPress'?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to call `didChangeDependencies` when `RefreshIndicator` `onRefresh` is triggered. Is that even possible? This is my code/try:

```
RefreshIndicator(
  onRefresh: () {
    return didChangeDependencies;
  },
  child: ...
),
```

But this code is giving me an error

> The return type 'void Function()' isn't a 'Future', as required by the closure's context.

Can you tell me how I can make this code to work, when I have some business login in the `didChangeDependencies` and I want to reused it when `onRefresh` is triggered?

EDIT: I also tried this way

```
RefreshIndicator(
  onRefresh: didChangeDependencies,
  child: ...
),
```

But I am getting other error then:

> type '() => void' is not a subtype of type '() => Future'

EDIT2: This is my didChangeDependencies method

```
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isInit) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      standings = Provider.of<Matches>(context).standings;

      if (standings.length == 0) {
        Provider.of<Matches>(context).fetchStanding().then((fetchedStandings) {
          standings = fetchedStandings;
          if (mounted) {
            setState(() {
              _isLoading = false;
            });
          }
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      }
    }

    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

Comment: Why you are not creating a separate method and calling it from both OnRefresh and didChangeDependencies?

Comment: Yeah, I can do that, but I wanted to ask if calling didChangeDependencies is even possible. I was wondering....

Comment: you can call it, it just a normal method

Comment: Yes, but it seems so I have to convert it so it returns void instead of Future<void>, but how I can do this and what will be the code?

Comment: any reason for calling `didChangeDependencies`? what do you want to achieve by doing that?

Comment: @pskink, to not repeat the logic I have already written there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would extract the whole function in didChangeDependencies, then call it inside didChangeDependencies along with     super.didChangeDependencies();

then use the new function in the :

```
RefreshIndicator(
  onRefresh: () {
    newFunction();
  },
  child: ...
),
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer has a better approach than this, but to address your specific question:

You got 90% of the way there in your update and comment.

> type '() => void' is not a subtype of type '() => Future'

onRefresh returns a Future. That's different than say, a RaiseButton's onPressed which will return a non-Future.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RefreshCallback.html

So you need to give it a Future. You could, for example, mark didChangeDependencies as async.